# Why the scholarship deadline extended?

Tags: deadlines

I am applying for a scholarship and just submit all the documents one day before deadline. One week later, I checked the scholarship website and found that the deadline has been extended 3 weeks. Does anyone know the reason the deadline extended? Is it unfair?

Comment: I get puzzled when people ask questions in a way which absolutely guarantees that there is not enough information to answer them.  We are not clairvoyant: we don't know which scholarship you applied to or what their reasons are for extending the deadline (hence we don't know if it's "unfair", although that seems quite subjective even with complete information).  In this case you are probably not going to find out why they extended the deadline, and given that it does not adversely affect you in any evident way, my advice would be just to let it go.  (I've voted to close.)

Comment: I agree with the above. However, to give some hint, I want to tell you academic deadlines are often (if not always) extended. Conferences, scholarships, special issue contributions etc. The first deadline can be seen as a first call. But don't count on it to happen!

Comment: I've seen calls with a massive **WARNING: DEADLINE WILL NOT BE EXTENDED!!!!**, which somehow illustrates people assume it normally will.

Comment: Shows how common it is to extend them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scholarship deadlines are sometimes extended because the sponsoring organization would like to see more people apply. To do so, they extend the deadline. I do not know if this is the case in your particular situation. However, I have known this to occur in other situations.